# Uploading Product Brand CSV in magento2

Tags: product-attribute, csv, file-upload, import-products

We have 67 products where we have just uploaded but the "Product Brand" has not been selected.

I have tried the following:
A singular coloumn with title "product_brand": Rudy Project (in cells).
Additional attributes with cells showing "product_brand=rudy project"

Both have not worked.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Michelle

Comment: Did you provide correct product brand name? for example; your csv is a in first column define manufacturer column in ad values of product brand i.e hp, dell. hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to assume the data structure for product CSV imports into Magento. I'd advise that you do the following:

- Find a product with "Brand" data already defined correctly via admin panel (or manually set data for this attribute to a product)
- Run a product export, filtered by this single SKU
- See what the CSV data looks like from the export
- Match the export data structure for "Brand" attribute in your import CSV

This approach usually works for me. Hope it helps!